# Install Monokai Theme on Terminal with prompt colors, etc.?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, color, sublimetext

I already have a Monokai theme installed in Terminal, as so:

[image]

I was wondering how I could get the rest of the Monokai (as Sublime uses) into Terminal? Like, making the prompt (Gamma@~) colored, etc.

Here is my current .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
export PS1="\u@\w $ "
alias ls='ls -G'
```

Thank you very much! I know this question is rather vague, but I cannot seem to find a PS1 color scheme that matches Monokai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124409) on the Unix & Linux SE. There are a number of additional colors that can be used in a 256 color terminal.

You can view the colors in Terminal, and see their codes, by running this bash script. (There is a also a color chart in the above linked post, or IMO a more readable chart [here](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#colors1).)

```
#!/bin/bash

color=16;

while [ $color -lt 245 ]; do
    echo -e "$color: \\033[38;5;${color}mhello\\033[48;5;${color}mworld\\033[0m"
    ((color++));
done
```

Once you determine the colors you want, and have the color codes, you can use them in a PS1 prompt like shown below.

`48;5;#` where # is the color number you want, sets the background color.

`38;5;#` again # replaced with the color number, sets the foreground color.

In my case I wanted the default background that Terminal set when it was launched, and I use `0` to note this. (You can also see that toward the end of the sequence `\[\e[0m\]` - same idea, using 0 to reset everything to the default.)

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;38;5;166m\]\u@\H\[\e[0m\] \w $ '
```

The below screenshot shows my original, default prompt, and then how it looks when I sourced `.bash_profile` after defining `PS1`:

[image]

Comment: I've started using iTerm2 and zsh, but this is still relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but have you looked at [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/)? It comes with several additional features on top of Terminal, and you can download and install a whole bunch of sweet themes on top of it. Apart from iTerm, I can also recommend zsh, which is just an additional layer on top of the bash shell, and if you use the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) plugin, again, you get a whole bunch of pre-cooked themes and prompts.